# Create Get Set Properties from Table Name for Views in Class

Tags: t-sql, fetch

The below code is a quick script in T-SQL which builds Get Set properties for use in a CLASS:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME varchar(250)
DECLARE @DATA_TYPE varchar(250)
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR

select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Members'
OPEN c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar'
BEGIN
    SET @DATA_TYPE = 'string'
END

IF @DATA_TYPE = 'ntext'
BEGIN
    SET @DATA_TYPE = 'string'
END

IF @DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
BEGIN
    SET @DATA_TYPE = 'DateTime'
END


PRINT 'public ' + @DATA_TYPE + ' ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' { get; set; }'

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE

END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
GO
```

IF you can add to it or clean it up, it would be great!

**UPDATE**
The below code is working and I made some slight modification.

```
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Script = @Script + '
public ' + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar','ntext') THEN 'string' 
                WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' THEN 'DateTime' 
                ELSE DATA_TYPE
            END 
                        + ' ' 
                        + upper(substring(COLUMN_NAME,1,1))+
                        + lower(substring(COLUMN_NAME,2,499))   
                        + ' { get; set; }'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SubCategory'

PRINT @Script
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the cursor and shorten it quite a lot with

```
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Script = @Script + '
public ' + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar','ntext') THEN 'string' 
                WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' THEN 'DateTime' 
                ELSE DATA_TYPE
            END 
                        + ' ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' { get; set; }'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Members'

PRINT @Script
```

Comment: Nice. I was too lazy to fire up SSMS to do it ;p And +1 in particular for fixing the casing on the info-schema tables - a pain in case-sensitive mode, otherwise.

Comment: Love it! Nice piece of clean coding and easy to follow. Great Job!

Answer (score 2):

If it does what you need... *stop tinkering* ;p If you want feedback:

- no need for that cursor; a set-based `SELECT` should suffice; anytime you find yourself writing  a cursor it is *probably* wrong
- either join to a mapping table (between SQL types and C# types), or use `CASE ....` to pick inline
- you *might* want to be paranoid about reserved words, for example `public` - in C# you'd need to use `@public` for that (or avoid it)
- you might want to remove spaces; you can call a db column `[something with spaces]`, but that won't work in C#
- you could check the extended metadata for an `MS_Description` value, and write that into (one of, or perhaps both) the `///<summary>...</summary>` or `[Description(@"...")]`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'Members'
declare @result varchar(max) = ''

select @result = @result + '
public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName, 
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'char'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
        end ColumnType
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t

print @result
```